# writing an array(json serialization)

Tags: java

```
 public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    String[] str = value.split(",");

    gen.writeStartArray();

    for (String inputAadhaar : str) {

        String output = SearchSerializer.service.encrypt(input);
        gen.writeString(output);

    }

    gen.writeEndArray();

}
```

It works fine and i am getting output like
     {"numbers":["XXXXX,XXXXXXXX"]}
Is there any way to replace or remove the array braces.
i want output like  {"numbers":"XXXXX,XXXXXXXX"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing the array start and end. Just collect all the numbers into a single string:

```
public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    String[] str = value.split(",");
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(i != 0){
            output.append(',');
        }
        output.append(SearchSerializer.service.encrypt(str[i]));
    }
    gen.writeString(output.toString());
}
```

Comment: @madhuri glad I could help. If this answers your question completly you may want to accept it.